# creating element in javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
  function mail_login(url) { 
    alert(url);
    var form=getElementById('autologin');
    var input1=document.createElement('input');
    input1.id='autologin_name';
    input1.type='text';
    input1.name='Username';
    form.appendChild(input1);

    var input2=document.createElement('input');
    input2.id='autologin_password';
    input2.type='text';
    input2.name='Password';
    form.appendChild(input2);
    document.getElementById('autologin').action=url;
    document.forms[0].username.value = 'xxx'; 
    document.forms[0].password.value = 'xxx'; 
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
  }

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form id='autologin' method="post" target='_blank'> 

<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="mail_login('https://inchnm02.tcs.com/names.nsf?Login');" >click here to login to your tcs mail</a><br>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

if i put the elements directly inside the form then it works fine.like below.

```
<input type="text" name="Username" /> 
<input type="text" name="Password" />
```

Comment: `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById` instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and see what errors you get and which lines they point to.

Comment: i changed it but still i am not able to login

Comment: Seriously, look in the error console and fix all the errors. (You're referring to things by wrong names.)

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. `document.forms[0].username.value` should be `document.forms[0].Username.value`, and the same for the password.

Comment: And why are you using `document.forms[0]` when you have a nice variable `form` for that? You can also use `input1.value` and `input2.value`.

Comment: ...frankly, it would be easiest to just drop the JavaScript and do this in plain HTML and hidden input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var form=getElementById('autologin');
```

I believe it is document.getElementById

Comment: This is only one of the problems.